# Integration by parts with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $u$ is a complex-valued wave function $u(x,y,z,t)$. Also, suppose you have the integral $\int(u\overline{u}_{t}+u_{t}\overline{u})dx$. I need to get $\int(u\overline{u}_{t}+u_{t}\overline{u})dx$ to equal $2 Re(\int u_{t}\overline{u}dx)$, and I am told that I need to use integration by parts in order to do this. The only thing is, I have never done it even seen integration by parts with complex valued functions before, especially bit ones that are functions of 4 variables. Could somebody please show me how to do this integration? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: write $u=a(t)+ib(t)$ and $u_t=a_t+ib_t$.

Hint 2: no integration by parts